# Getting file information from directory given in command line parameter

Tags: ruby

been working on a program for school and need assistance getting some pieces.

The goal is to take in a command line parameter of any directory and display some information about each file that has extensions.  I have it mostly working, but need help on some extra's.

The file just needs a couple more things:

1. Group the extensions and count them.
2. Take in more than one parameter, and default to the current directory if one isn't given.
3. Count the number of each / display the total size / and give a display error if the directory doesn't exist or if I can't access it.

Currently, it does get the files from the directory, displays the extension, and puts out the size of the file.  Here's the code I've written thus far:

```
directory=ARGV[0]
searchstring= Regexp.new "(\\.[^.]+)$"


if File.exists? File.expand_path(directory)
Dir["#{File.expand_path(directory)}/*"].each.map  { |f| File.basename(f)


   if File.basename(f)=~searchstring
   puts "Extension: #{File.extname(f)} Count:  Size: #{File.stat(f).size}"
   end
}
else
puts "This directory does not exist"
end
```

The output looks like this so far:

```
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 104
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 381
Extension: .xml Count:  Size: 84252
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 107
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 377
Extension: .sql Count:  Size: 1763
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 123
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 189
Extension: .db Count:  Size: 10240
Extension: .rb Count:  Size: 791
```

EDIT: I have it checking if the directory exists.  I'm going to paste in my new code above.  Still need help with other things though.  Particularly with storing the extensions as a group (hash?).

Comment: I've tried multiple iterations of ARGV.each do, but I can't get it to cycle through multiple command line parameters no matter what I try.

I'm still lost on having it look at all subdirectories from the given parameter as well.

Comment: I've rolled back the edits a bit on this, try to avoid updating your question with the answer, and instead up vote helpful answers and accept the most helpful answer. This way, future readers can see what problems you were having and how Peter was able to help you instead of just seeing that Peter's answer is the exact same code as posted in the question. If you have further questions, consider posting a new question and linking back to this one, if additional context is required

Comment: Thanks Simple Lime.  I thought I was doing a favor by updating.  I'll keep this in mind for future issues.  I'll probably post an updated question tomorrow and link back to this one.

Answer (score 2):

On your second question: `ARGV[0] || Dir.pwd` should do the trick or `File.dirname(__FILE__)`

I suppose you want a hash of the extensions in that folder with a count and size of each extension, that should be something like this

```
directory = ARGV[0] || Dir.pwd
searchstring = Regexp.new "(\\.[^.]+)$"

extensions = Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = {size: 0, count: 0}}

if File.exists? File.expand_path(directory)
  Dir["#{File.expand_path(directory)}/*"].each.map do |f|
    if File.basename(f) =~ searchstring
      extensions[File.extname(f)][:size] += File.stat(f).size
      extensions[File.extname(f)][:count] += 1
    end
  end
else
  puts "This directory does not exist"
end

p extensions
```

In case you are wondering what the `Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = {size: 0, count: 0}}` means:
You assign a default value to the hash `extensions` which is a hash with default contents {size: 0, count: 0}
You need the size and count to be 0 and not nil since you do a `+=` on it and that's not possible on nil

Comment: I get an error with this: "uninitialized constand DIR (NameError).  I even just tried using if ARGV=empty? directory=DIR.pwd.  I got the same error

Comment: it's Dir, not DIR, Ruby is case sensitive,  part of the standard library so should work with MRI Ruby versions a way back, also the Dir[***] method is quite powerfull in using wildcharts for paths and extensions, so you could skip the seachstring part

Comment: I really appreciate the help.  I was really stuck with how I would put these into a hash and this is exactly what I needed.  What would be the easiest way to display these on separate lines.  I tried a puts and it still puts all extensions on the same line.

Comment: NM, figured out how to put it on separate lines.